# Xubuntu Xenial Google Earth can not recognize graphics card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, google, google-earth

I have two computers executing Xubuntu Xenial 32 bits GeForce 7025 Graphics Processor. NVIDIA Driver Version:304.132

Since yesterday, Google Earth ,it was running perfectly crash, informing:

```
can not recognize graphics card
```

Crashlog:

```
Major Version 7
Minor Version 1
Build Number 0007
Build Date Oct  6 2016
Build Time 20:55:36
OS Type 3
OS Major Version 4
OS Minor Version 4
OS Build Version 0
OS Patch Version 0
Crash Signal 11
Crash Time 1478988963
Up Time 10,262

Stacktrace from glibc:
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e5cc9)[0xb7316cc9]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e5e71)[0xb7316e71]
[0xb76f7c14]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x61)[0xb6805141]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1db)[0xb680681b]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x168)[0xb68055a8]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x61)[0xb6805141]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1db)[0xb680681b]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10showNormalEv+0x5c)[0xb67f852c]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN10MainWindow18readScreensizeInfoEv+0xcd6)[0xb72eb676]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client11Application12SetupMainWinENS0_3Kvw7ProductEb+0x314)[0xb73b1dc4]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client11Application3runEv+0x73d)[0xb73b575d]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x1e59a4)[0xb73169a4]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(earthmain+0x2ec)[0xb731719c]
./googleearth-bin[0x804889b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb74c6637]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running it with administrator permissions and it runs perfectly.

```
sudo /opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f
```